# how to get first max or min value from table in PowerBI?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

This is my table:

[image]

I want to get only max value out of that, that is 71 and its date also and min value also. I am getting this table by distinct count of temperature filed.(without using expression).

I can also set it to multi row card besides table,  sort it ascending or descending so that it will show sorted rows and will resize it like this:

[image]

but user can maximize it also using the icon on top right corner. Is it possible to remove that icon(customize the title bar icon) ?
Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: What source are you using? excel? SQL Server? SSAS?

Comment: using sql server.

Comment: I can suggest a SQL query that will get what you're after if that helps

Comment: Alternatively you can add a measure `MaxTemp = Max(Temperature)`

Comment: @Mogli, was my suggested solution not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a measure and a combination of the functions `max()` and `Lookupvalue()`

I'm using this data to show you how:

```
Date,Temp
09.04.2016,1
10.04.2016,2
11.04.2016,3
12.04.2016,4
13.04.2016,5
14.04.2016,81
15.04.2016,20
16.04.2016,30
17.04.2016,40
18.04.2016,50
19.04.2016,60
20.04.2016,70
21.04.2016,71
```

Insert that dataset and split it on `,`.

Then add a new measure and insert the following function:

```
Max = "Max value for this period is "& max(Table1[Temp]) & " on " & LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Date]; Table1[Temp]; max(Table1[Temp]))
```

Now you an add a multi row card visualization and insert your measure to get:

[image]

And you can add this formula to get the min value:

```
Min = "Min value for this period is "& min(Table1[Temp]) & " on " & LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Date]; Table1[Temp]; min(Table1[Temp]))
```

[image]

And since it seems you like multi-row cards you can have both measures in the same card:

[image]